# VBA function refuses to return a string

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

```
Function getExcelFolderPath2() As String

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    
    Dim fullPath As String
    
    fullPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(ThisWorkbook.Name)
    
    fullPath = Left(fullPath, Len(fullPath) - InStr(1, StrReverse(fullPath), "\")) & "\"
    
    getExcelFolderPath2 = fullPath

End Function
```

Even though fullPath gets a string with relevant contents, getExcelFolderPath2 ends up being empty. This is from a break on that last line, just to be clear:

[image]

There must be something really simple that I'm missing, but I can't see it.

I expected to have getExcelFolderPath2 be equal to fullPath.

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling the function?

Comment: Then use `getExcelFolderPath2 = fullPath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a comment than an answer, but too long:

I guess the function works correctly. It works for me (and at least for user Dominique).

Could it be that you set the breakpoint on the statement `getExcelFolderPath2 = fullPath` and then look to the Locals Window? When the runtime hits that statement and breaks, the statement itself is not executed.

[image]

But if you step to the end of the function, the function value is set

[image]

Call the function from the immediate window to check:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what it was! That, combined with a bug in the way I called it caused me so much confusion.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is working fine.

How do you call that function? I have simplye put `=getExcelFolderPath2()` inside a cell (like "B3").

Oh, did you add the Microsoft Scripting Runtime in your list of VBA references? (VBA editor, "Tools" menu, "References" item)

Comment: Ok, i figured it out. I had set the break on the equals line, which of course is before that line is actually processed. And the reason I was investigating was because there was actually a bug in the line where I called the function, just as you hinted at. So problem solved!

Comment: @MartinBerg: Glad I could help. If my answer helped you, please upvote it for reference reasons.